# What is the men's version of Trek Lexa SLX

Tags: identify-this-bike, trek

Trek used to make only "WSD" versions of the same model names sold "for men."  But things aren't that simple anymore!  What's the men's version of the [Lexa SLX](http://www.trekbikes.com/us/en/bikes/road/endurance_race/lexa/lexa_slx_compact/)?

Comment: A quick check of BikeRadar it seems like the Slique is closest to a Domane-Madone mix, and the Lexa relaxes it a bit. In any case, the question is a bit boring from the practical side, since the rider needs to try out the bike anyway. Manufacturers are also trying build bikes to be more for women "from the ground up" making it trickier (and giving the bikes more effeminate names doesn't make it simpler either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking around their site, the [Madone 2.1](http://www.trekbikes.com/us/en/bikes/road/performance_race/madone/madone_2_1_h2_compact/) seems to have similar components, yet is only $1,319.99 compared to the Lexa which is $1,649.99.  Looking over the specs,  I can't see why there is such a discrepancy in the price.  The [Domane 2.3](http://www.trekbikes.com/us/en/bikes/road/endurance_race/domane/domane_2_3_compact/) is also quite similar and has the IsoSpeed decoupler on the frame and appears to hace rack mounts based on the picture. It is priced at $1,869.99.

There also seems to be a substantial price difference between the [Silque](http://www.trekbikes.com/us/en/bikes/road/performance_race/silque_womens/silque_compact/) and the very similar [Emonda S4](http://www.trekbikes.com/us/en/bikes/road/performance_race/emonda/emonda_s_4/), which are priced at $2,089.99 and $1,649.99 respectively.  It's interesting that the women's specific models seem to be so much more expensive.  Maybe there's something I'm missing out on with the pricing.

Comment: The Madone 2.1 is not the same frame at all.  Note the seat tube: Lexa has the IsoSpeed decoupler in the frame, and rack mounts, where the Madone 2.1 has neither.  The Madone 2.1 on the other hand has internal routing of the shift cables, where Lexa does not.  They're quite different frames.

Comment: What do you think about the Domane 2.3?  It has basically identical components to the Lexa SLX except for the saddle.  The frame is not identical, but similar, with IsoSpeed and rear rack mounts.  The shape of the frame is pretty different, but still the same "Alpha 200" material.  It costs $1869.99, $220 more than the Lexa (not sure why).

Comment: The Domane 2.3 has an IsoSpeed fork, which the Lexa does not have and could account for some of the price difference. The saddle will be different as the one on the Lexa is womem specific.

Answer (score 1):

I have bought 6 bikes in the last 5 years.  5 of those bikes have been Trek bikes. Not because I love the brand, but because the bike shop that I bought the bikes from tries really hard to make my wife happy.  Our LBS tries really hard to keep her on the road, and that is not an easy thing. she's 5'2" with a long torso and short legs. Not exactly the easiest fit for road bikes and mountain bikes.

Long story, short.  We visited every single LBS in a 35 mile radius from our house and as soon as my wife tried one bike, or as soon as they saw her, we got turned away with nothing more than a "sorry, we have no bikes that will fit your body type."

As a last ditch effort, we visited what is now "our" LBS (the only one I visit now, four years later).  They told us about their extensive line of bikes and how they could find a bike for her.  Trek Skye 13".  Four bikes later (all Trek brand btw), I've become a bit of a Trek fanboy.

These are the line of bikes as I understand them.

- The 1-series and the Lexa series are parallel to each other.
- The 1-series is non-gender specific, and the higher end 1.5 is just a little short of being in the Madone series.
- The lexa series is specifically dialed for women's bodies, with the higher end Lexa SLX just being short of being in the Silque series.
- The silque and the Domane Series are also parallel to each other. These are made to balance speed and comfort.
- The silque series is specific for women.
- The Domane series is non-gender specific.
- The Madone is their primary road bike.  Not much on comfort, it's all about the speed.
- The Emonda is the Madone series on a severe diet. Speed with as little weight as possible.  The Emonda series is not race legal, but unless you are a pro-cyclist, it doesn't matter.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: The lower end Emonda's are race legal as far as I'm aware, with the lowest end one weighing in at 19.27 lbs.  It's not until you get into the high end $5,000 models where the weight drops below the UCI weight limit of 15 lbs, with the most expensive one weighing in at a measly 10.25 lbs.